# Jqgrid headers are disturbed in IE 10?

Tags: internet-explorer, jqgrid

My jqgrid is working right but when i open in IE its headers disturbed. Headers become small and their column gets the right display. Only headers are distrubed. I have tried many things to do it but nothing working.What should i do?

Oleg its working on all browser except IE.

Comment: What you mean under "My jqgrid"? Which version and which fork of jqGrid you use? There are no common compatibility problem with IE10 (at least if you don't use some retro version of jqGrid). **Could you provide the demo which can be used to reproduce the problem?** You should at least post the code which you use. It's unclear from the current text which options of jqGrid you use (data or column grouping, TreeGrid, subgrids, frozen columns etc). It could be important which other CSS frameworks (like Bootstrap) you use.

Comment: I added a snapshot.Please see

Comment: I am not using (data or column grouping, TreeGrid, subgrids, frozen columns etc)

Comment: I see just that you use `direction: "rtl"`, `multiselect: true` and `rownumbers: true` option, but **all other questions from my previous comment are opened**. The starting point is **which version and which fork of jqGrid you use?** One can't analyse screenshot and to find out which CSS rules are applied to the column headers. I can include another screenshot which looks correctly, but it helps you to fix your code. The most quickly way to find the reason of your problem: to debug the demo which you should provide.

Comment: JQGrid version is 4.4.4. Bootstrap version : 3.3.5 . just add one css in auto complete  loadComplete: function () {
                $("tr.jqgrow:odd").css("background", Common.jqGrid.alternateRowColor);
            }, it change the color of jqgrid rows

Comment: jqGrid 4.4.4 not compatible with Bootstrap. Bootstrap set many CSS rules which will be applied to jqGrid and which breaks the calculation of width. Try to change URLs to jqGrid files to URLs described in [the article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). I suppose that your grid will looks correctly.

Comment: for the answer. thanks for the answer. you always help me in JQGrid pronblem

Comment: You are welcome! Is the problem solved now? Looks all correctly with free jqGrid? Can you upgrade jqGrid 4.4.4 to free jqGrid 4.9.x in your project?

Comment: not resolved but i will see this later. I have no rights to upgrade jqgrid. But i will tell to my team lead.